# PIXI.JS: CORS issues with Cloudfront+S3 after switching Origin from API Gateway to NGINX

Tags: amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront, nginx-reverse-proxy, pixi.js

## Problem Summary

I have an JS/PIXI application, which is served from an (1) Origin and loads images via CORS from (2) S3. Recently I have changed the setup of the Origin to NGINX and now I get CORS-issues which I can't explain.

I have set up CF+S3 for CORS, and the corect headers reach my JS application. However I still get errors in my new setup, but not in my old setup. The only difference between those is that the original JS application passes NGINX instead of API Gateway, but I don't see why that should make a difference.

## The new setup

- Origin

  - JS Application -> AWS Cloudfront -> NGINX (reverse proxy) -> Tomcat
  - The JS code will try to load an image from S3
  - Example: https://clawcrane-staging.myshopify.com/ (check out your dev console)
- CF+S3 (CORS)

  - Cloudfront -> S3
  - Example: https://s3.app-staging.secretbakery.io/clawgame/clawcrane-staging.myshopify.com/83/cat.png

## The old setup

- Origin

  - JS Application -> AWS Cloudfront -> **AWS API Gateway** -> Tomcat
  - Example: https://fabios-colors.com/ (here you first need to click the box on the top-right and go through the chat)
- CF+S3 (CORS)

  - Cloudfront -> S3
  - Example: https://s3.app.secretbakery.io/clawgame/fabios-colors.myshopify.com/82/star-cartoon-png-8.png

## Problem Details

When I check out the dev console for the new setup, CORS headers are sent from CF+S3 to the browser. Still I am getting CORS errors with the new setup, but no errors with the old setup.

#### Response headers NEW setup (errors)

```
accept-ranges: bytes
access-control-allow-methods: GET, HEAD
access-control-allow-origin: *
content-length: 2737
content-type: image/png
date: Fri, 07 Feb 2020 06:54:14 GMT
etag: "f17401d09e8e68fdd5e1e4f5f2d6c078"
last-modified: Mon, 03 Feb 2020 06:44:03 GMT
server: AmazonS3
status: 200
vary: Origin,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Access-Control-Request-Method
via: 1.1 50f438df6dbb947f3e4702890bc9cc06.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: wDaNwtpDRoiFKGaxQ5HgJLPIAiDiCR24O5HNJQ7imwl-BNU9SvyF3g==
x-amz-cf-pop: DUS51-C1
x-cache: RefreshHit from cloudfront
```

#### Errors I get

The http request returns with 200 ok. The error I get is:

```
GLTexture.js:94 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The image element contains cross-origin data, and may not be loaded.
    at n.upload (https://pixijs.download/v4.8.5/pixi.min.js:8:23427)
    at t.updateTexture (https://pixijs.download/v4.8.5/pixi.min.js:13:9592)
    at e.bindTexture (https://pixijs.download/v4.8.5/pixi.min.js:13:17291)
    at e.flush (https://pixijs.download/v4.8.5/pixi.min.js:15:4210)
    at e.stop (https://pixijs.download/v4.8.5/pixi.min.js:15:4619)
    at e.setObjectRenderer (https://pixijs.download/v4.8.5/pixi.min.js:13:15173)
    at e._renderWebGL (https://pixijs.download/v4.8.5/pixi.min.js:11:14045)
    at e.renderWebGL (https://pixijs.download/v4.8.5/pixi.min.js:10:23992)
    at e.renderWebGL (https://pixijs.download/v4.8.5/pixi.min.js:10:24068)
    at e.render (https://pixijs.download/v4.8.5/pixi.min.js:13:14986)
```

#### Response headers OLD setup (no errors)

```
accept-ranges: bytes
access-control-allow-methods: GET, HEAD
access-control-allow-origin: *
age: 2365
content-length: 116268
content-type: image/png
date: Fri, 07 Feb 2020 06:58:37 GMT
etag: "71858c64f78ce419cdcd4d8f21839332"
last-modified: Wed, 05 Feb 2020 11:28:15 GMT
server: AmazonS3
status: 200
vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers,Access-Control-Request-Method
via: 1.1 e5dcf90f3787d486ad40e46070021460.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: 2LZVSXwwTWkcJ1LShQqfp2ZB4jPMe4Olp7CjOHO6gsGlsUCBxrvlNQ==
x-amz-cf-pop: DUS51-C1
x-cache: Hit from cloudfront
```

#### S3 CORS Setup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

#### Cloudfront CORS Setup

I have whitelisted `Access-Control-Request-Headers` and `Access-Control-Request-Method`.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: What’s @JoelWiklund said. Also, what’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: Added error details. I believe now that this is actually not a CORS problem with the request/response itself, but rather how the CORS image data is further processed in the PIXIJS library. Otherwise I would have errors that indicate that CORS-Headers are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Alright guys, I got the solution. This is a CORS problem, not on HTTP/browser level, but rather on the level of the JS application (PIXIJS/Webcanvas).

The requests and responses are done correctly and the JS application receives the image data. However I have learned that certain operations are not okay for images read from a CORS context (see https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-cors-permission.html , https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/42303-pixiloader-with-cors/).

To prevent PIXIJS from conducting illegal operations on CORS images, I have added a `crossOrigin` flag when loading them:

```
PIXI.loader.add(url , {crossOrigin: 'anonymous'});
```

What I don't understand however is why this has worked in my old setup (with AWS API Gateway).